# How can I integrate a EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup as a label for an EditorGUILayout.IntSlider?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am currently using a simple `IntSlider` as seen in the code below:

```
 rotAngle = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("rotation", obj.rotationAngle, -angleRange, angleRange);
```

I need to implement a more advanced slider that changes one parameter at a time. I need to implement an enum for my slider label. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the label enum

```c#
public enum Label
{
     A,
     B,
     C
}
```

Now you can do something like

```c#
int rotAngel;
Label label;

EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
label = (Label)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(label);

rotAngle = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider(obj.rotationAngle, -angleRange, angleRange);
EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

I just added `BeginHorizontal` and `EndHorizontal` assuming you want to display both fields next to each other.

Also note that you always have to parse to your enum  `(Label)` because `EnumPopup` returns an `int`.